# Drop element from list in a column if it startswith certain character

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a column in dataframe consisting of lists of URLs.

```
    index        url_all
    0       ['https://google.com/7TU4za', 'http://twitter.com/d']
    1       ['https://google.com/7TU4bb', 'facebook.com']
    2       ['https://google.com/7TU4bc', 'https://twitter.com/a']
    3       ['http://google.com/7TU4ad', 'https://twitter.com/b']
    4       ['https://google.com/7TU4ze', 'twitter.com/c']
```

I want to remove elements in the list if it starts with 'http' or 'https'. The desired output is here.

```
    index        url_all
    0       []
    1       ['facebook.com']
    2       []
    3       []
    4       ['twitter.com/c']
```

So far I have tried the following, but it did not work.

```
df['url_all'] = df['url_all'].apply(lambda lst: [x for x in lst if not x.startswith("'http|'https")])
```

It gives this output as below (for brevity, only the first few rows of the output are shown):

```
              url_all
[[, ', h, t, t, p, s, :, /, /, g, o, o, g, ..]]
[[, ', h, t, t, p, s, :, /, /, g, o, o, g, ..]]
[[, ', h, t, t, p, s, :, /, /, g, o, o, g, ..]]
[[, ', h, t, t, p, :, /, /, g, o, o, g, ..]]
[[, ', h, t, t, p, s, :, /, /, g, o, o, g, ..]]
```

How can I do that please?

Comment: That looks like your `url_all` values are strings, not lists...

Comment: Note testing for `startswith('https')` is redundant because those strings would also match `startswith('http')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.apply()` with `ast.literal_eval()` (note that anything that starts with `"https"` will also start with `"http"`, per a suggestion from [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/nick)):

```py
import ast

df['url_all'] = (df['url_all']
    .apply(ast.literal_eval)
    .apply(lambda lst: [x for x in lst if not x.startswith("http")]))
```

This outputs:

```py
   index          url_all
0      0               []
1      1   [facebook.com]
2      2               []
3      3               []
4      4  [twitter.com/c]
```

Comment: Anything that matches `https` will also match `http`...

Comment: I think this is probably the most correct solution as OPs result suggests that the values are strings, not lists of strings

Comment: @Nick. The answer can be greatly optimized. `df['url_all'].apply(lambda lst: [x for x in ast.literal_eval(lst) if not x.startswith("http")])`

Comment: @Corralien What makes your approach faster?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark. Only one apply (1 loop) instead of 2 apply (2 loops).

Answer (score 1):

I think this fixes your problem.

First, I made the same DataFrame you have:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [['https://google.com/7TU4za', 'http://twitter.com/d'], ['https://google.com/7TU4bb', 'facebook.com'], ['https://google.com/7TU4bc', 'https://twitter.com/a'], ['http://google.com/7TU4ad', 'https://twitter.com/b'], ['https://google.com/7TU4ze', 'twitter.com/c']]
dictionary = {'url_all':data}
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
```

This gave the following, like you have:

```
            url_all
    0       ['https://google.com/7TU4za', 'http://twitter.com/d']
    1       ['https://google.com/7TU4bb', 'facebook.com']
    2       ['https://google.com/7TU4bc', 'https://twitter.com/a']
    3       ['http://google.com/7TU4ad', 'https://twitter.com/b']
    4       ['https://google.com/7TU4ze', 'twitter.com/c']
```

Then, the following line gave me the result you wanted. Note that anything that starts with `https` also starts with `http`, so we don't have to check both conditions:

```py
df['url_all'] = df['url_all'].apply(lambda lst: [x for x in lst if not x.startswith('http')])
```

Now, the DataFrame looks like this, as desired:

```
            url_all
    0       []
    1       ['facebook.com']
    2       []
    3       []
    4       ['twitter.com/c']
```

Comment: Note testing for `startswith('https')` is redundant because those strings would also match `startswith('http')`

Comment: @Nick good point, edited my answer.

Comment: I think OPs data is probably strings, based on their result. However if they were lists this would be the right way to process them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
df['url_all'].apply(lambda lst: list(filter(lambda url: not url.startswith('http'), lst)))
```

output:

```
>>> df['url_all'].apply(lambda lst: list(filter(lambda url: not url.startswith('http'), lst)))
0    [twitter.com/c]
1     [facebook.com]
2    [twitter.com/c]
3                 []
Name: url_all, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have strings, this can be solved efficiently with a regex:

```
df['url_all'] = df['url_all'].str.replace(r"'http[^']*'(?:,\s*)?", "", regex=True)
```

Variant to handle the dangling commas:

```
regex = r"(?:,\s*)?'http[^']*'(?:,\s*)?(?=\]$)|'http[^']*'(?:,\s*)?"

df['url_all'] = df['url_all'].str.replace(regex, "", regex=True)
```

Output:

```
             url_all
0                 []
1   ['facebook.com']
2                 []
3                 []
4  ['twitter.com/c']
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try using this code,,

```
class CleanLink:
"""class that clean stuff"""
def __init__(self,list):
    #creat a list attribute
    self.list = list
    
def clean(self):
    clean_links = [] #empty clean link list
    
    for x in self.list: #looping through list attribute
    
        if 'https://' in x: #looking for https
            without_https = x.replace('https://','') #using replace method
            clean_links.append(without_https) #appending the clean link
        
        elif 'http://' in x: #looking for http
        
            without_http = x.replace('http://','') #using replace method
            clean_links.append(without_http) #appending the clean link
            
        else:
            clean_links.append(x)#appending the clean link
    return clean_links #returing the clean link
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this one

```
class CleanLink:
"""class that clean stuff"""
def __init__(self,list):
    #creat a list attribute
    self.list = list
    
def clean(self):
    clean_links = [] #empty clean link list
    
    for x in self.list: #looping through list attribute
    
        if 'https://' in x: #looking for https
            continue
        elif 'http://' in x: #looking for http
            continue        
        else:
            clean_links.append(x)#appending the clean link
    return clean_links #returing the clean link
```

Comment: You didn't explicit how to use this class with OP's data, but this is likely overkill (and inefficient or non-functional) here

Comment: You just creat a CleanLink instance by passing a list as argument...and after that u use .clean method ,,thats all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to filter out your column and convert values to real list:

```
df['url_all'] = (df['url_all'].str[1:-1].str.split(', ').explode().str.strip("'")
                              .loc[lambda x: ~x.str.startswith('http')]
                              .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
                              .reindex(df.index, fill_value=[]))
print(df)

# Output
           url_all
0               []
1   [facebook.com]
2               []
3               []
4  [twitter.com/c]
```

1. Remove brackets and split on comma `.str[1:-1].str.split(', ')`
2. Explode your lists and strip quote `.explode().str.strip("'")`
3. Keep expected values `.loc[lambda x: ...]`
4. Reshape your dataframe and create list: `.groupby(level=0).agg(list)`
5. Reindex the output and fill nan values by empty list `.reindex(...)`